# Export result from oracle to excel or txt?

Tags: oracle, export

How do you export a result from an ORACLE database to a excel or txt with only scripting?

for instance like

export to c:\file.xls 
select * from table1

or something like that?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do it from within Excels VBA

```
Sub DisplayDBATables()

  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  cn.Open ( _
    "User ID=rene"        & _
    ";Password=my_secret" & _
    ";Data Source=XE"     & _
    ";Provider=MSDAORA.1" )

  rs.Open "select * from dba_tables", cn

  Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165427%28v=office.10%29.aspx) *Copies the contents of an ADO or DAO Recordset object onto a worksheet, beginning at the upper-left corner of the specified range. If the Recordset object contains fields with OLE objects in them, this method fails.*

Comment: Hi, I tried doing it from the "Immediate" but I get an error where it says "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch",
And when i try to run it from the "General" I get an error user-defined type not defined. 
Any help here? I have never used vba other than some super simple update script for the cells.

Comment: Did you add the reference to use ADODB from within Excel?

Comment: No but I don't know how to do it though.
A description how to do it in detail would be nice! :)
I don't have any ADODB under the "References" that I can check.

Comment: Never mind I found it,
The reference needed is "Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.x Library". It is installed when you install MDAC 2.x from MS downloads.
THANKS FOR THE HELP! :)

Answer (score 0):

The export (exp) command is used to export data in a binary format (suitable for backup).
Using sqlplus, you can use the spool command to export a query's result to a text file.

[More on using spool info here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/spool.html)

That said, it is easier to do it using a tool like toad or sql developer.

Comment: "That said, it is easier to do it using a tool like toad or sql developer."  Could you tell me how to export a query result to a txt file through the query or script?